# How to Add White Space at the end of word while Inserting Data into MySQL?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, mysql-workbench

```
create table Test(aa varchar(20),bb varchar(20),cc varchar(20),primary key (aa,bb));

 insert into Test values('abc','ab','a');

 insert into Test values('abc  ','ab','a');

 insert into Test values('abc','ab  ','a');

 insert into Test Values('abc  ','ab  ','a');
```

Here if I'm executing this statements  I'm getting error in the third line as

> Error Code: 1062. Duplicate entry 'abc -ab' for key 'PRIMARY' 0.250 sec.

But I want to insert that whitespaces at the end of word .How to do it in MySQL.

For more info click here dbfiddle.uk :
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=43da399bc1254611553172544abae8f8

Answer (score 0):

This is [a documented behavior](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/blob.html):

> If a TEXT column is indexed, index entry comparisons are space-padded at the end. This means that, if the index requires unique values, duplicate-key errors will occur for values that differ only in the number of trailing spaces. For example, if a table contains 'a', an attempt to store 'a ' causes a duplicate-key error.

So you just can't do that. Consider using something else than spaces to disambiguate your values.